# Regular expression matching with string slice in Go

Tags: parsing, regex, go

I have a slice of strings, and within each string contains multiple `key=value` formatted messages. I want to pull all the keys out of the strings so I can collect them to use as the header for a CSV file. I do not know all potential `key` fields, so I have to use regular expression matching to find them.

Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)
func GetKeys(logs []string) []string {
        // topMatches is the final array to be returned.
        // midMatches contains no duplicates, but the data is `key=`.
        // subMatches contains all initial matches.
        // initialRegex matches for anthing that matches `key=`. this is because the matching patterns.
        // cleanRegex massages `key=` to `key`
        topMatches := []string{}
        midMatches := []string{}
        subMatches := []string{}
        initialRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`([a-zA-Z]{1,}\=)`)
        cleanRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`([a-zA-Z]{1,})`)

        // the nested loop for matches is because FindAllString
        // returns []string
        for _, i := range logs {
                matches := initialRegex.FindAllString(i, -1)
                for _, m := range matches {
                        subMatches = append(subMatches, m)
                }
        }

        // remove duplicates.
        seen := map[string]string{}
        for _, x := range subMatches {
                if _, ok := seen[x]; !ok {
                        midMatches = append(midMatches, x)
                        seen[x] = x
                }
        }
        // this is where I remove the `=` character.
        for _, y := range midMatches {
                clean := cleanRegex.FindAllString(y, 1)
                topMatches = append(topMatches, clean[0])
        }
        return topMatches
}


func main() {
    y := []string{"key=value", "msg=payload", "test=yay", "msg=payload"}
    y = GetKeys(y)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

I think my code is inefficient because I cannot determine how to properly optimise the `initialRegex` regular expression to match just the `key` in the `key=value` format without matching the value as well.

Can my first regular expression, `initialRegex`, be optimised so I do not have to do a second matching loop to remove the `=` character?

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/ONMf_cympM

Comment: `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`, and if the Go `regexp` package supports it, you can use positive look-ahead to detect but not capture the `=`: `[a-zA-Z]+(?=\=)`. IIRC, the second `=` doesn't need to be escaped since it has no special meaning outside of this context. Finally, I doubt you need the capturing group around the whole expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not making good use of regular expressions. A single regex can do the job:

```
pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`([a-zA-Z]+)=`)
```

The parentheses `(...)` are the capture the interesting part for you.

You can use `result = pattern.FindAllStringSubmatch(s)` to match a string against the regex pattern. The return value is a `[][]string`, where in each `[]string` slice, the 1st element is the entire matched string, and the 2nd, 3rd, ... elements have the content of the capture groups. In this example we have one capture group `(...)`, so the value of the key will be in `item[1]` of each `[]string` slice.

Instead of a `map[string]string` map for `seen`, a `map[string]boolean` would be more efficient.

Putting it together:

```
func GetKeys(logs []string) []string {
    var keys []string
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`([a-zA-Z]+)=`)

    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, log := range(logs) {
        result := pattern.FindAllStringSubmatch(log, -1)
        for _, item := range result {
            key := item[1]
            if _, ok := seen[key]; !ok {
                keys = append(keys, key)
                seen[key] = true
            }
        }
    }

    return keys
}
```

If the input strings are not guaranteed to be in the right format matching the pattern, then you might want to add a guard statement inside the main for loop, for example:

```
    if len(result) != 2 {
        continue
    }
```

Comment: I was reading about submatches, but I wasn't entirely sure if that's what I wanted or not because I didn't understand that was for capture groups. That makes a lot of sense. What is more efficient about a boolean over the string?

Comment: @mynameismevin the storage of a `bool` is smaller than a `string`

Comment: The original code used `FindAllString` to find multiple matches per message, but yours uses `FindStringSubmatch` which looks to return a single match.

Comment: A `map[string]struct{}` is even more efficient and uses less memory than `map[string]bool`.

Comment: @OneOfOne really? how? and how would I change the line `seen[key] = true` to make that work?

Comment: @DavidHarkness you were absolutely right, I fixed it now

Comment: @mynameismevin my solution had a bug, pointed out by David, that it did not match multiple keys per message. It's fixed now.

Comment: @janos to set `seen[key] = struct{}{}`, to check `if _, ok := seen[key]; ok {}`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it popped up in my feed so I figured I'd contribute.

Out of curiosity, why use a regular expression at all? You could achieve the same thing use standard strings package and keep things simple. Here's a [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B8pxwFQ2x4v) that outputs the same result as your Playground.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func GetKeys(logs []string) []string {
    exists := make(map[string]bool)
    keys := make([]string, 0)
    for _, log := range logs {
        parts := strings.Split(log, "=")
        if len(parts) >= 1 {
            k := parts[0]
            if !exists[k] {
                keys = append(keys, k)
                exists[k] = true
            }
        }
    }
    return keys
}

func main() {
    y := []string{"key=value", "msg=payload", "test=yay", "msg=payload"}
    fmt.Println(GetKeys(y))
}
```